# How to copy object's dimension from another object?

Tags: objects, dimensions

I am learning Blender and just stuck on one thing.
I have two Objects (A and B), A's length is 400 and B's length is 100.
I want to make B's length half of A's length.
like whenever I change A's length, B's length should automatically get change to its half.
But I don't want to do it with python script.
is there any way to put some simple code/defination/name in Blender's UI, where we manually enter object's length (under Dimensions - after clicking 'N' after selecting the object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there any way to put some simple code/defination/name in Blender's UI

Indeed. It's called a [Driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html):

[image]

You can also use a constraint - but then you have to modify the mesh to be 4 times shorter, as the constraint copies the scale 1 to 1:

[image]

Documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much Markus